# JavaScript + Spring MVC - how to get a value from an object sent from the controller?

Tags: javascript, spring

I'm trying, without success, to get a String value directly from the pojo sent from my controller to the HTML page, parse it into an array and build an editable grid with it.

The implentation is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var emails = eval(${pojo.resultEmailRecipients});

    var list = emails.split(",");

    var metadata = [];
    metadata.push({ name: "email", label: "EMAIL", datatype: "email", editable: true});

    var data = [];
    var id = 1;
    for (email in list) {
        data.push({id: id, values: {"email": email}});
        id++;
    }

    editableGrid = new EditableGrid("DemoGridJsData");
    editableGrid.load({"metadata": metadata, "data": data});
    editableGrid.renderGrid("table1", "testgrid");   
});
```

Ideally this will he rendered at:

```
<div id="table1"></div>
```

But Firebug reports and error getting the object.

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    var emails = eval(${pojo.resultEmailRecipients});
```

What's going on here?

Comment: you are missing the closing bracket for the "ready" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is this variable ${pojo.resultEmailRecipients} with eval function, eval expects an expression not a pojo.
try to change your code to 
 var emails = pojo.resultEmailRecipients;

Comment: I managed to get it working by using `<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">` and `var result = [[${pojo.resultEmailRecipients}]];`.